# how to specify the paths for boost so as to build dlib successfully on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boost, cmake, face-recognition, dlib

I'm trying to install face-recognition on ubuntu but dlib keeps failing to build. I tried running `python3 setup.py install` but it returned some error about boost. After installing boost it still can't locate it.

1. how can I specify the paths for boost(for /path/to/dir/boost_1_78_0 and /path/to/dir/boost_1_78_0/stage/lib)
   An online source suggested that I append it to the CMakeLists.txt but there are two files with that name in the dlib-19.6 folder.ie. /path-to-dir/dlib19.6 has CMakeLists.txt and /path-to-dir/dlib19.6/dlib also has CMakeLists.txt. which one is the right one?
2. how can I solve the issue below:

   /tmp/pip-install-md97yl8n/dlib_c8973decd1e045cb9182990e2e1f228e/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:112:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   112 | #include <Python.h>
   |          ^~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.

which is part of the error message output by the terminal when I run `pip install face-recognition`

3. is there any way that I could automatically install dlib and boost and have the system automatically specify the necessary paths?

Comment: Python.h : `sudo apt install python3-dev` .............. About boost : Where did you install boost_1_78_0   ? ..... And *face-recognition* : `pip install face-recognition` https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 example : `dpkg -s libboost-all-dev` → Version: 1.71.0.0ubuntu2 . ........ `sudo pip install face-recognition` : Successfully installed dlib-19.23.1 face-recognition-1.3.0 face-recognition-models-0.3.0

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thankyou for the fast reply. I'm quite new to linux so I'm not sure where I installed boost. How can I check for binaries of installed software?

Comment: Well, you could just install the default boost : `sudo apt install libboost-all-dev` , which is perfect for dlib/face-recognition. ...... Finding installed files, e.g. with `locate libboost_filesystem.so.1.78`

Comment: I've tried pip install face-recognition.. it didn't work and neither does installing the dependencies for boost. I'm thinking about uninstalling ubuntu and starting over